# Explicit cast to T on generic method required in some cases

Tags: generics, c#-4.0

I have a situation that is confusing me and was hoping for some help. In the code below the FindById method works without having to cast the return but the UpdatedAuditedEntity call doesn't. Note that:

1. AuditedEntity derives from Entity
2. Casting auditedEntity to an Entity doesn't work, only casting to T works.

Any insight into what I'm missing here would be greatly appreciated. At first I thought it had to do with variance but as I mentioned above I tried down casting with no sucess.

```
    public class NHibernateRepository<T> : NHibernateBase,
    IRepository<T> where T : Entity
{

    public IEnumerable<T> FindAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var query = GetQuery(predicate);
        return Transact(() => query.ToList());
    }

    public T FindById(int id)
    {
        // TODO: Why does this work when below doesn't
        return FindAll(e => e.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private T UpdateAuditedEntity(T item)
    {
        var auditedEntity = item as AuditedEntity;

        if (auditedEntity == null) return item;

        auditedEntity.DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow;

        // TODO: figure out why this cast is necessary
        return auditedEntity as T;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> AuditedEntity derives from Entity

OK, but in this generic class, `T` is of an **arbitrary** derivative of `Entity`. The compiler doesn't care that your `auditedEntity` was created by casting `item` - indeed, there could be custom conversions at play here doing unexpected things - so doesn't allow you to return a variable *typed* as `AuditedEntity` from a method that asks for a `T`.

In this particular method, since `item` and `auditedEntity` are **the same** object, you can just do

```
return item;
```

as the last statement of `UpdateAuditedEntity` and the compiler will be happy.

Answer (score 2):

This is necessary because although both AuditedEntity and T are derived from Entity, AuditedEntity may not inherit whatever type is represented by T.

For example, say you created a type "OtherEntity" that directly inherited Entity.  An instance of  `NHibernateRepository<OtherEntity>` would have UpdateAuditedEntity return an AuditedEntity, which does not inherit OtherEntity - so the returned type would not be valid.

Comment: That's true in general, but look at the body of `UpdateAuditedEntity` - if `T` *isn't* (an) `AuditedEntity`, it returns null. At the problem line, *we* know more about `T`, but the compiler doesn't

Comment: @AskashM: Your point is valid and practical for avoiding the conversion in the method body, but I interpreted the question to be why can't the OP return an AuditedEntity-typed instance from the method.  OP seemed to be under the misapprehension that inheriting from Entity would make the conversion unnecessary.